# Azure CLI: unable to update NIC parameters

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli

So i need to script detaching Load Balancer's backend pool from NIC to update our live machines, but i have a strange problem while updating NIC from CLI.

I can set whole 'loadBalancerBackendAddressPools' group to null with --set or remove key, but when this is a last property in a group - i can't update it.

```
az network nic update --resource-group MyPreciousGroup -n machineNetworkInt01020 --set ipConfigurations.[0].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools.[0].backendIpConfigurations=null
```

this throws an error:

```
Operation failed with status: 'Not Found'. Details: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1234-1234-1234-0000000000/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/australiaeast/operations/1111111-1234-1234-1234-1111111111?api-version=2017-03-01
```

Btw, is there a way to update whole property group with JSON or something? All that i want to setup after machine updates with parameters below:

```
loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
    {
      "backendIpConfigurations": null,
      "etag": null,
      "id": "/subscriptions/111111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/resourceGroups/MyEnvironment-AustraliaEast/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/MyLoadBalancer/backendAddressPools/MyBackendPool",
      "loadBalancingRules": null,
      "name": null,
      "outboundNatRule": null,
      "provisioningState": null,
      "resourceGroup": "MyEnvironment-AustraliaEast"
    }
  ],
```

Python 2.7.12

azure-cli 2.0.7

Comment: I test your script in my lab, I get the same result with you. You could use `az` like my answer. It works for detaching nic from backend pools.

Comment: Just tried your way - it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the following commands to detach NIC from Load Balancer backend pools.

```
az network nic update -g <your group name> -n <nic name> --set ipConfigurations[name=<ip-config-name>].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools=[]
```

Following script is an example, it works for me.

```
az network nic update -g shuiload -n shui0 --set ipConfigurations[name=ipconfig1].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools=[]
```

Also, you could use Azure CLI to add NICs to backend pools.

```
az network nic update -g ${resource-group} --name ${nic-name} --add ipConfigurations[name=${ip-config}].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools id=${backend-address-pool-id}
```